# Receive data via USART on Atmel SAMD20

Tags: serial, uart, atmel

I'm trying to receive some data via USART on Atmel SAMD20. I use `usart_read_wait()` and `usart_read_buffer_wait()` but they return with error: the first with `STATUS_BUSY` and the second with `STATUS_ERR_TIMEOUT`. Sending works great, I get all the bytes in Putty or minicom. Here is my code:

```
#include <asf.h>

static struct usart_config usart_conf;
static struct usart_module usart_mod;

int
main (void)
{
  system_init();
  usart_get_config_defaults (&usart_conf);
  usart_conf.pinmux_pad0 = PINMUX_UNUSED;
  usart_conf.pinmux_pad1 = PINMUX_UNUSED;
  usart_conf.pinmux_pad2 = PINMUX_PA20D_SERCOM3_PAD2;
  usart_conf.pinmux_pad3 = PINMUX_PA21D_SERCOM3_PAD3;
  usart_init (&usart_mod, SERCOM3, &usart_conf);
  usart_enable (&usart_mod);
  stdio_serial_init (&usart_mod, SERCOM3, &usart_conf);

  uint8_t buf[8];
  enum status_code st = usart_read_buffer_wait (&usart_mod, buf, sizeof (buf));
  printf ("Code: %d\r\n", st);
}
```

The uC is connected to the PC via USB-to-TTL serial adapter.
I suspect that I did the pinmux configuration the wrong way. I don't really understand what pinmuxes and pads are. So how could I send some data to the uC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you fix this? It would be great if you could include the complete code you are using. 
In case you didnt, try putting your usart initialization inside a while cycle.

```
while (usart_init(&usart_instance,
            EDBG_CDC_MODULE, &config_usart) != STATUS_OK) {
    }
```

The usart needs some time to complete the initialization process, if you dont use that, it will always fail in the first try. 
Remember to replace EDBG_CDC_MODULE with the SERCOM you are using in your project